# How can I use Django to have persistent session variables?

Tags: python, django

I have a trigger in my database that will automatically update the row_modified_by_user column based on the value of a session variable.

To do this in Django, I believe I would have to put this in my settings.py file:

```
'my_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'my_db_name',
    'USER': 'my_db_user',
    'PASSWORD': '******',
    'HOST': 'my_host',
    'PORT': '12345',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': "SET @SessionForUser = '" + CURRENT_USER + "'",
    }
}
```

Now, CURRENT_USER is the user being logged in.  How do I pass this value from my views.py to my settings.py?

Note that I can't use a connection cursor in my views.py because the connection is not persistent, it is closed afterwards so the session variable is cleared after it executes the command:

```
with connections['my_db'].cursor() as cursor:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SET @SessionForUser = '" + CURRENT_USER + "'")
```

I can't use global variables either because this is used only for reading (not writing) values:

```
settings.CURRENT_USER = username
```

What would be a good alternative for this?  Maybe I am approaching this problem incorrectly?

Comment: You definitely are approaching this incorrectly, but it's hard to know what the correct approach would be. Generally you should assume there is nothing persistent between requests in Django (or any web app). Why can't you do this at the form or view level rather than relying on connection settings?

Comment: In the view level, any connections I make are temporary and the sessions terminate, invalidating any session variables I have defined.

Comment: Yes, which is why I said not to use session variables. That is not the way to do it.

Comment: Then how would you do it?  I've coded these session variables for my previous framework before moving to Django.  That way, I don't have to list on every of my insert and update web pages an SQL that does "update row set <changes>, modified_by = 'username'";

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so considering Daniel's comment, I've decided to use a different approach:

This is now what I use in my save method:

```
def save(request, form):
[...]
   item = form.save(commit=False)

   if item._state.adding:
       item.created_by_username = request.user.username
   else:
       item.modified_by_username = request.user.username

   item.save()
[...]
```

Additionally, my database has triggers to update the timestamp when the username field is updated.  Alternatively, I could have done the django way by using this instead for those timestamps:

https://timonweb.com/tutorials/automatic-created-and-updated-datetime-fields-for-django-models/